# Modifying Quartz.NET job details after they've been scheduled

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a Quartz.NET application where I need the administrators to be able to  modify the job details - mostly information in each jobs datamap, but also things like the triggers - here is my code I'm using

```
   protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JobDetail jobDetail = sched.GetJobDetail(hdnID.Value, hdnGroupID.Value);
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["idname"] = txtName.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["initialPath"] = TextBox1.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["targetPath"] = TextBox2.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["regex"] = TextBox3.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["overrideemails"] = txtEmails.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["flush"] = chkflush.Checked;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["impUsername"] = txtImpUsername.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["impDomain"] = txtImpDomain.Text;
        jobDetail.JobDataMap["impPassword"] = txtImpPassword.Text;
        Trigger[] triggers = sched.GetTriggersOfJob(hdnID.Value, hdnGroupID.Value);

        if (ddlScheduleType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            foreach (SimpleTrigger trigger in triggers.OfType<SimpleTrigger>())
            {
                if (ddlInterval.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    trigger.RepeatInterval = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01");
                }
                else if (ddlInterval.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    trigger.RepeatInterval = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
                }
                else if (ddlInterval.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    trigger.RepeatInterval = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01");
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (CronTrigger trigger in triggers.OfType<CronTrigger>())
            {
                trigger.CronExpressionString = txtCron.Text;

            }
        }


    }
```

(I know what I'm doing with the foreach loops is stupid, but there is only ever one trigger with a job and it's a snippet of code I recieved here).

Problem is, the page posts back fine and the new values still stay in the textboxes. But when I go view the job again, nothing changes at all. What am I doing wrong? It's confusing as there are no errors at all.

Note the hiddenfields are also correctly set.

Thanks

The ButtonSubmit_Click event is certainly working as I've debugged the program and the program goes through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance you get by calling `sched.GetTriggersOfJob` and `sched.GetJobDetail` are clones of the real triggers / jobs.
Your changes to those objects are not used by the scheduler until you reschedule the changed trigger or add a the changed job with the changed trigger.

I think you should be able to use [RescheduleJob](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/44656a29-199e-7373-5547-e20318780802.htm) if you only change the triggers and you could [remove](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/ff17ee5c-4ba8-34e5-6dfc-600a13a6de2e.htm) the original trigger and [add](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/84be9956-052d-05d7-4366-0837fcd6d78b.htm) a new one.